# How can I get actual values from pandas df in sns.distplot displayed on x axis

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, histogram

I'm trying to create an histogram made of data I got as homework.
when I'm trying to plot it, values on the x axis are different (0.0-1.0) from those in the actual dataset (20,000 - 1,000,000).
How do I get the range of actual values from my data to be displayed on the x axis of the histogram instead?

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('okcupid_profiles.csv')
df = df[df['income'] != -1]

income_histogram = sns.distplot(df['income'], bins=40)
income_histogram
```

[the histogram I've created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECKkf.png)

Thanks

Comment: You can use `ax = sns.distplot(...)` and then `ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain', axis='y')`.  Note that `sns.distplot` doesn't return a histogram, but a handle to the subplot on which it was drawn.  Also note that in the latest seaborn versions `distplot` has been replaced by `histplot(...., kde=True)`

Answer (score 0):

The values displayed in the x-axis are the same on the dataset, if you can see in the bottom right corner there is 1e6, that mean :
`0.1 * 1e6 == 100,000`